# MySQL - How do I make my max_allowed_packet setting stick?

Tags: mysql

I've edited `my.ini` in the directory where MySQL is installed and inserted 
`max_allowed_packet=50M` under the `[mysqld]` section, but when I launch the MySQL command line and do:

```
show variables like 'max_a%'
```

It still shows a value of 1048576.  I've rebooted the box, but to no avail.

**EDIT:** I believe the issue was that MySQL was reading one of the (many) other config files (e.g., my-huge.ini).  I re-ran the MySQL config wizard and it appears to be honoring the settings in my.ini now.

(**btw:** Why so many configs?!?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following page shows the different directories from which MySQL reads the configuration files:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely confusing 'global' and client variables.  Try:

show global variables like 'max_a%';

Make sure you're specifying the option under "[mysqld]" as well.  Dominik's recommendation regarding modifying the correct config file is key, regardless.